# What does this block of C code do in order to find the end character?

Tags: c

```
char *start = str;
char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1; /* -1 for \0 */
char temp;
```

How does that find the end of the string? If the string is `giraffe`, `start` holds that string, then you have:

`char *end = "giraffe" + 7 - 1;`

How does that give you the last char in giraffe? (`e`)

Comment: I am not sure what your question is , but in general 
`*end` is a pointer and code `char *end = start + strlen(str) - 1;` sets it to point to the last char in the word

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how `"giraffe"` is laid out in memory, with each number giving that character's index.

```
g i r a f f e \0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

The last character `e` is at index 6. `str + 6`, alternatively written as `&str[6]`, yields address of the last character. This is the address of the last character, not the character itself. To get the character you need to dereference that address, so `*(str + 6)` or `str[6]` (add a `*`, or remove the `&`).

In English, here are various ways to access parts of the string:

```
 str ==   str + 0  == &str[0]        address of character at index 0
     ==   str + 6  == &str[6]        address of character at index 6
*str == *(str + 0) ==  str[0]        character at index 0 ('g')
     == *(str + 6) ==  str[6]        character at index 6 ('e')
```

Comment: But theoretically, `g` could be stored at 281 for example, and the other letters follow it, right?

Comment: Yep, that's right. If `g` is at address 281 then `e` will be at 287.

Comment: One thing I would like to add to your reply to @DougSmith's comment is that strings in C are arrays of characters whose indices always start at 0. So I hope that by 281 you mean that `g` is stored at address 281 or that the letter `g` appears in a really long string at position 281 instead of thinking that the array can start at an index of 281. Sorry if I'm over-thinking/misunderstanding it...

Answer (score 3):

> If the string is giraffe, start holds that string

Not exactly, `start` is a `char *`, so it holds a pointer, not a string. It points to the first character of "giraffe": `g`.

`start + 1` is also a `char *` pointer and it points to the next element of size `char`, in this case the `i`.

`start + 5` is a pointer to the second `f`.

`start + 6` is a pointer to the `e`.

`start + 7` is a pointer to the special character `\0` or NUL, which denotes the end of a string in C.

Comment: Then why am I able to `printf()` `start` and get `giraffe`?

Comment: @DougSmith Because printf expects a pointer to the start of a string, when you tell it to expect that with `%s`. It then loops through the  characters printing each one until it reaches the `NUL`.

Answer (score 2):

start is a pointer to the string "giraffe" in memory, not the string itself.

Likewise end is a pointer to the start of the string + 7 bytes (minus one to account for the null terminator).

Comment: Why in that case is `start` a pointer in memory, while in `printf()` it returns the actual string?

Comment: Because printf prints the string that's pointed to by its argument.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `string` type in C, just `char`, and arrays of `char`.

I would tell you to google "c strings", but since that's apparently a term that you need safesearch for these days, here's a link: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html

Comment: Answers should be pretty much self-contained and not merely reference external links. I encourage you to expand on this so it stands alone whether or not one visits the link.